# Converting Database records from eastern time to gmt

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a handful of tables on my DB one in particular that is originally set based on eastern time. It has 12k+ records, and I am trying to find a sane approach to coverting the datatime records on these tables to match a gmt datetime equivalent without having to build a loop that will cycle over all the rows one by one updating them. Is that possible to do efficiently or am I going to have to loop over them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

What about [`ADDTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function? You can update all the column you need with a simple query

Comment: That may work for some of my issue, unfortunately however. No one to into account the timezone offsets from people east to west or in other regions of the world. So what we have ended up with are seriously conflicting logs coupled with conflicting stock data

Comment: The end goal is to get everything fixed up and syncing properly by basing everything off a gmt date/time and adjusting with the offset of the persons location

Comment: @chris I see i tought you only need to update dates. This is getting harder then

Comment: Yea.. its rough, but one step at a time. In order to get things working as desired, I have to start somewhere.. and converting the times over seems like the logical first step, cause once the data I will be working with to fix the code is proper, I can then fix the code as needed where needed to compensate

Comment: @chris this is probably the best approch you cam have to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONVERT_TZ() function. But before any manipulation try to make a backup (copy for example your column to another one called timetest)

Then Try this :

```
UPDATE table_name SET timecolumn = CONVERT_TZ(timecolumn,'EST','GMT');
```

Comment: I found a post on Stack about that just a minute ago due to your reference. What I am confused about is, it seems that I have to install something or reconfigure SQL as a whole to use it properly? Is this understanding correct?

Comment: something to do with the servers current location vs the way sql is initially configured?

Comment: Errrr...I don't think so, take a look there https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz
It Works that way :
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2013-04-20 18:00:00','EST','GMT');

Comment: Glad I cloned the table, to try it first. Running that changed all the datetimes to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` :-\

Comment: Ouch!! :( Which type is your datatime? Could you give us an example

Comment: Try this : 
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(timecolumn,'-05:00','00:00')
And tell me what does it return.